# ListLinePlot over a plot image respecting the axes scale and coordinates

Tags: plotting, image

I have the following array of points:

```mathematica
results = {{0.00001, 1.02875*10^-18}, {0.0000125893, 
  1.68649*10^-18}, {0.0000158489, 3.05807*10^-18}, {0.0000199526, 
  4.70025*10^-18}, {0.0000251189, 7.79949*10^-18}, {0.0000316228, 
  1.99933*10^-17}, {0.0000398107, 3.07791*10^-17}, {0.0000501187, 
  6.48224*10^-17}, {0.0000630957, 1.29902*10^-16}, {0.0000794328, 
  2.06383*10^-16}, {0.0001, 4.37899*10^-16}, {0.000125893, 
  7.53215*10^-16}, {0.000158489, 1.26504*10^-15}, {0.000199526, 
  2.36106*10^-15}, {0.000251189, 4.6381*10^-15}, {0.000316228, 
  7.68628*10^-15}, {0.000398107, 1.40567*10^-14}, {0.000501187, 
  2.59503*10^-14}, {0.000630957, 4.65325*10^-14}, {0.000794328, 
  8.21835*10^-14}, {0.001, 1.41624*10^-13}, {0.00125893, 
  2.58447*10^-13}, {0.00158489, 4.42212*10^-13}, {0.00199526, 
  7.75571*10^-13}, {0.00251189, 1.31187*10^-12}, {0.00316228, 
  2.32723*10^-12}, {0.00398107, 3.80149*10^-12}, {0.00501187, 
  6.4725*10^-12}, {0.00630957, 1.07687*10^-11}, {0.00794328, 
  1.73726*10^-11}, {0.01, 2.78838*10^-11}, {0.0125893, 
  4.25353*10^-11}, {0.0158489, 6.32114*10^-11}, {0.0199526, 
  8.96078*10^-11}, {0.0251189, 1.19384*10^-10}, {0.0316228, 
  1.48594*10^-10}, {0.0398107, 1.87604*10^-10}, {0.0501187, 
  2.47836*10^-10}, {0.0630957, 3.60395*10^-10}, {0.0794328, 
  4.82006*10^-10}, {0.1, 5.39711*10^-10}, {0.125893, 
  4.98985*10^-10}, {0.158489, 3.75711*10^-10}, {0.199526, 
  2.35183*10^-10}, {0.251189, 1.4464*10^-10}, {0.316228, 
  8.21802*10^-11}, {0.398107, 4.40408*10^-11}, {0.501187, 
  2.35047*10^-11}, {0.630957, 1.29265*10^-11}, {0.794328, 
  7.46674*10^-12}, {1., 3.77453*10^-12}, {1.25893, 
  2.17292*10^-12}, {1.58489, 1.12382*10^-12}, {1.99526, 
  5.8518*10^-13}, {2.51189, 3.30812*10^-13}, {3.16228, 
  1.76265*10^-13}, {3.98107, 9.46619*10^-14}, {5.01187, 
  5.23966*10^-14}, {6.30957, 2.85806*10^-14}, {7.94328, 
  1.48685*10^-14}, {10., 7.74828*10^-15}, {12.5893, 
  4.2486*10^-15}, {15.8489, 2.3633*10^-15}, {19.9526, 
  1.2738*10^-15}, {25.1189, 6.51306*10^-16}, {31.6228, 
  3.5344*10^-16}, {39.8107, 1.84255*10^-16}, {50.1187, 
  9.99582*10^-17}, {63.0957, 5.43049*10^-17}, {79.4328, 
  2.7573*10^-17}, {100., 1.45355*10^-17}, {125.893, 
  7.5014*10^-18}, {158.489, 3.94472*10^-18}, {199.526, 
  2.0092*10^-18}, {251.189, 1.02983*10^-18}, {316.228, 
  5.41701*10^-19}, {398.107, 2.77729*10^-19}, {501.187, 
  1.41885*10^-19}, {630.957, 6.83971*10^-20}, {794.328, 
  3.52343*10^-20}, {1000., 1.71697*10^-20}}
```

which look like this

```mathematica
ListLinePlot[results,ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"f(Hz)", "Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], GW] h^2"},PlotRange->{{ 10^-4,10^2},{10^-18,10^-6}}]
```

[image]

I would like to `ListLinePlot` the array over the image (from here https://cds.cern.ch/record/2709470/files/strain.png)

[image: Test]

while respecting the coordinates, i.e. the point `{0.00001, 1.02875*10^-18}` should land on the same point on the coordinate system of the plot in the image.

I've been going through a lot of Googling to do this and I am at a lost. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure that there is a systematic approach. That's just going to be a lot of tedious fiddly trial and error. I'm also not sure that anybody but you yourself would have enough interest in this niche task to do it for you.

Comment: I'm aware that there might not be a systematic approach, I was just wondering if anyone else had any good ideas on how to go about it. However, I don't know if I agree with anybody else being interested in this task: plotting predictions over experimental sensitivities is common practice in many scientific areas. I did it in the past, with the fiddling approach, and I was just hoping for more ideas.